# No output of a code that counts characters of a string

Tags: java, string

I faced a problem while writing a code that counts the characters 
of a string.
Generally the code looks right but when i try to run it it gives me no output!
I don't know exactly where is the problem, hope you can help me to figure it out.

Here is the code:

```
    String S1;
    char letter=0,number = 0,space=0,Schar=0;

    System.out.println("Enter the string:");
    S1=input.nextLine();

    int size=S1.length();

    for(int index=0; index<size;index++){
    char ch=S1.charAt(index);

    if(Character.isLetter(ch)){
    letter++;
    }else if(Character.isDigit(ch)){
    number++;
    }else if(ch==' ')
    space++;
    else 
    Schar++;

    }

    System.out.println("The string is: " +S1);
    System.out.println("Letter: " +letter);
    System.out.println("Number: " +number);
    System.out.println("Space: " +space);
    System.out.println("Other: " +Schar);

The output:
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKtrG.png)

Comment: Why are your variables `char`s instead of `int`s? You are counting the occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

This [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) explains your empty output. The characters mapped to the first integers aren't visible. The first visible character seems to appear at number `32`. If you had written a longer string you would probably have seen some output.

Change `char` to `int` and everything should be fixed, as follows:

```
int letter = 0, number = 0, space = 0, Schar = 0;
```

These variables are made to count the number of occurrences of each type of character and should therefore be of the type `int`, not `char`.